# Can a 10*10 binary puzzle have more than 1 solution?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, solvability

I was trying to solve 10*10 binary puzzle and when I checked with the answer given in the book, the solution in it was different from mine. I did not repeat 1 or 0 more than twice in any row or column. Is it possible to have more than 1 solution in a binary puzzle.

Comment: Are you sure that in your solution all the rows are distinct, and all the columns are distinct?

Comment: What kind of puzzle are you talking about here?

Comment: "Binary puzzle" is a common type of logic grid puzzle, as seen [here](http://www.binarypuzzle.com/rules.php).

Comment: You've mentioned that your solution met one of the rules (no contiguous identical triplets), but there are other rules you didn't mention: each row and column should have the same sum, no two rows are identical, and no two columns are identical.

Comment: This puzzle is also known as Unruly in Simon Tatham's puzzle collection.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by "a 10×10 binary puzzle". But it's possible that the designers of the puzzle accidentally left the puzzle with multiple solutions. A pure logic puzzle *shouldn't* have multiple solutions, but authors do make mistakes.